# Способ передачи вложенной структуры JNI

Tags: jni, java, c++

Создана простая демо структура.
файл RECT.java

```
 public class RECT {
    long left;
    long right;
    long top;
    long bottom;
    }
```

Реализуется через JNI в linux

Файл APIMapacces.java

```
public class APIMapacces {
public APIMapacces(){
System.loadLibrary("apimapacces");
}
public native long rects(RECT rect);

}
```

Файл APIMapacces.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class APIMapacces */

#ifndef _Included_APIMapacces
#define _Included_APIMapacces
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     APIMapacces
 * Method:    rects
 * Signature: (LRECT;)J
 */
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_APIMapacces_rects
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

файл APIMapacces.cpp

```
   #include "APIMapacces.h"
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <istream.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include "mapacces.h"

    using namespace std;

RECT* javaRECT;
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_APIMapacces_rects
(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jobject rect){

javaRECT = new RECT();

jclass rectClass = env->FindClass("RECT");

jfieldID leftID = env->GetFieldID(rectClass, "left", "J");
jfieldID rightID = env->GetFieldID(rectClass, "right", "J");
jfieldID topID = env->GetFieldID(rectClass, "top", "J");
jfieldID bottomID = env->GetFieldID(rectClass, "bottom", "J");

javaRECT->left = env->GetLongField(rect, leftID);
javaRECT->right = env->GetLongField(rect, rightID);
javaRECT->top = env->GetLongField(rect, topID);
javaRECT->bottom = env->GetLongField(rect, bottomID);
return 0;
}
```

И основной файл для проверки Application.java

```
  public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("start");

APIMapacces _native = new APIMapacces();
long i;
RECT myRect = new RECT();
myRect.left = 5;
myRect.right = 10;
myRect.top = 15;
myRect.bottom = 20;
_native.rects(myRect);
i = myRect.left + myRect.right;
System.out.println(i);

}
}
```

Как передавать вложенную структуру, если например в файле RECT.java задать параметр bottom как структура с двумя значениями типа long?Например
bottom* Bottom;
файл bottom.java

```
public class bottom{
long x;
long y;
}
```

Comment: public class RECT { long left; long right; long top; BOTTOM* Bottom; } Вопрос ещё в силе!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Спецификацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#class_operations) читали? Еще прочтите [про сигнатуры классов и типов](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp16432).

Ваш код:

```
jfieldID bottomId = env->GetFieldID( rectClass, "Bottom",
    "Lcom.your.path.to.class.bottom;" );
jobject bottom = env->GetObjectField( rect, bottomId );
```

Только в Java нет явных указателей, так что не

```
public class RECT { long left; long right; long top; BOTTOM* Bottom; }
```

а

```
public class RECT { long left; long right; long top; Bottom bottom; }
```